# curl php authentication not working

Tags: php, authentication, curl

i know there are alot of questions out there but none solved my problem

i have to authenticate with uername and password and used curl as

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "/example.domain/tmp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pwd");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

but every time it just returns false.

I'm pretty new to using cURL so I could be making some beginner mistakes, but I'm confused as to why this isn't working at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing return transfer which is set to 1

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

write it before your CURLOPT_USERPWD i.e

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pwd");
```

then it might work. see if it work.

Comment: my pleasure. if this resolved your problem. Accept answer and mark it as resolved. :)